# Switch applying tests to forms

Tags: functions, function-construction, functional-style

Is it correct that the `Select` equivalent of `Cases` is missing for `Switch`?

I mean a function `switch[conditionFunction,form1,value1,form2,value2,...]`. Where `conditionFunction` would be a function that evaluates to `True` or `False` on the various forms, and switch would return the first value for which `conditionFunction[form]` evaluates to `True`.

What should I be using for this? If nothing pre-exists, what would be the best way to implement this.? (And why is this missing if we do have both `Select` and `Cases` by default?)

Comment: Perhaps `Which`is the function you're looking for.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, no, I don't want to have repeat the same test to be applied to all the forms. I do think that it is easy to write what I want using Which, with which I was already familiar, so I should have mentioned it in my question anyway.

Comment: Which repeats testing until the first True is detected!

Comment: Sorry that comment wasn't too clear. I meant since the test would be the same I don't want to have to type it for every entry just changing the argument. (That's better for readability and not just to save on the typing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch // Attributes = { HoldRest };

switch[foo_, spec__] /; EvenQ @ Length @ Unevaluated[spec] := 
  Which @@ MapAt[foo, Hold[spec], ;; ;; 2]
```

This way we will not evaluate `foo` with `forms` present after the correct one.

```
switch[True & @* Echo, a, 1, b, 2, c, 3]
```

> >> a
>
> 1

Comment: Thanks, with `SetAttributes[switch,HoldAll]` if we want it to behave as `Which` right? (Otherwise the forms are already evaluated before they are taken as input.)

Comment: @Kvothe correct, I didn't do this because I was not sure if holding them makes sense, but now I think it does. See the edit. I've also included arg length check.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
switch[f_, forms_, values_] := Which @@ Riffle[f /@ forms, values]
```

Usage example:

```
switch[# == "c" &, {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

However, this evaluates `f` over all forms , although it could also short-circuit.